# actions and services cons and pron

Tags: ros, actionlib, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know what differences that actions and services have in work and use?
when to use actions and when to use services in ros nodes?
And what cons and pron have been defined for them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30463/actions-and-services-cons-and-pron/) by [navidnabavi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1990/navidnabavi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS actions are intended for robot-actions that are expected to take a "longer" time. They provide a status where you can past the current expected status of the action (e.g. percentage or similar). For services, you will only get a result but no periodic status feedback. Furthermore, ROS actions offer the possibility to cancel the current action.

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5